# How to convert phone no column to text

Tags: php, excel

```
/*******************  For Excel Generate  ************************/
             $xls_header  = "USER ID"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "CUSTOM USER ID"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "USER NAME"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "E-MAIL"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "RESPONSIBLE E-MAIL"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "FIRST NAME"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "LAST NAME"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "ACTIVE"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "PHONE"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "MOBILE"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "PREFER NAME"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "TITLE"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "POSITION"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "COMPANY ID"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "DELIVERY COUNTRY"."\t";
             $xls_header .= "\n\n";
             $count = count($get_listing_user);
             $xls_value = "";
             $xls_value1 = "";
             $subtotal = 0;
             for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
             {
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->id."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->cust_user_id."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->username."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->email."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->risponsibleemail."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->first_name."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->last_name."\t";
                 if($get_listing_user[$i]->active == '1')
                 {
                 $xls_value.= " Active \t";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 $xls_value.= " De-Active \t";
                 }
                 if($get_listing_user[$i]->phone != '')
                 {
                    $xls_value.= '&nbsp;'.$get_listing_user[$i]->phone."\t"; 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      $xls_value.= "\t";
                 }
                 if($get_listing_user[$i]->mobile != '')
                 {
                    $xls_value.= ','.$get_listing_user[$i]->mobile."\t";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      $xls_value.= "\t";
                 }
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->prefer_name."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->title."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->position."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $get_listing_user[$i]->company_id."\t";
                 $xls_value.= $company_name_array[$i]."\t";


                /******************** For Delivery Address ********************/ 
                 $xls_value.= "\n"; 
             }
                 $xls_data = $xls_header.$xls_value;
                 $fname = 'FullCustomerReport-'.time().'.xls';
                 if (!write_file(FCPATH.'/ASSETS/'.$fname.'', $xls_data))
                     {
                     }
                     else
                     {
                           redirect('ASSETS/'.$fname);
                           unlink('ASSETS/'.$fname);
                     }
    /***************************  For Excel Generate  ************************/
```

How Can i Convert Phone no to Text string because some of phone numbers are start from 000545 , So all zero amount are removed when i download the excel . please suggest me option

i also tried put any sign like , | ` as prefix but its doesnt looks Good, so i want to put proper phone number. how can we convert field format from number to text

Comment: At least read about PHP's built-in fputcsv() function and save a lot of this painful code that attempts to do it in raw PHP

Comment: Then look at storing the value using `$xls_value.= '="'.$get_listing_user[$i]->phone."\"\t";` but remember that a csv file has very few options for any kind of formatting, so this is really little more than a workround

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) Library for that.

Where you can store it by below method.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '000545', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like :

```
$xls_value.= '&nbsp;'.strval($get_listing_user[$i]->phone)."\t";
```

Comment: Not Working &nbsp; can not take as a space it prints &nbsp;002365454 in excel

Comment: I think you was looking to convert the phone number to string and strval is fulfilling the requirements, Doesn't it?

Comment: no it doesn't convert the number to string because after all excel functionality grab only zero value . but thx for suggestion.